# Text in rowspan cell breaks on page break

Tags: itext

I am using iText 5.5.4 to generate a pdf.

I have a a bunch of rows that should be grouped together and have a rowspan cell to name the group. But, on page break, the word "GRP" is broken into "G"
 and "RP". Is there a way to make group unbreakable so that it will be drawn on next page if it can't fit on the current one?

I tried `keepRowsTogether` and `setBreakpoints`, but didn't get consistent results.

```
-------------------
| G |    row 1    |
| R |    row 2    |
| P |    row 3    |
-------------------
```

Layout Image:

[image: Layout Image]

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(300, 125));
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Table with setSplitLate(true):"));
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setWidths(new float[]{1,5});
table.setSpacingBefore(10);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("G"));
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("R"));
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("O"));
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("U"));
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("P"));

//PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase("GROUP"));
//cell.setNoWrap(true);
//cell.setRotation(90);
//cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
//cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

cell.setRowspan(5);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("row 1");
table.addCell("row 2");
table.addCell("row 3");
table.addCell("row 4");
table.addCell("row 5");
document.add(table);
document.add(new Paragraph("Table with setSplitLate(false):"));
table.setSplitLate(false);
document.add(table);
document.close();
```

[PDF Output from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpaq4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't provide any code which is kind of mandatory when you post a question on StackOverflow (unless you're not really interested in getting an answer), I have tried to write an example to reproduce the (undesired) result.

I didn't succeed. See my [SplittingAndRowspan example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/rowspan-and-splitting#1621-splittingandrowspan.java):

```
document.add(new Paragraph("Table with setSplitLate(true):"));
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setSpacingBefore(10);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("G"));
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("R"));
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("P"));
cell.setRowspan(3);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("row 1");
table.addCell("row 2");
table.addCell("row 3");
document.add(table);
```

I didn't really use `setSplitLate(true);` because the default value of the split late parameter is `true`. The result looks like this:

[image]

As the cell containing G R P doesn't fit the page, the table is forwarded to the next page (which is exactly what you want).

Of course, this doesn't happen when I use `setSplitLate(false)`:

```
document.add(new Paragraph("Table with setSplitLate(false):"));
table.setSplitLate(false);
document.add(table);
```

In this case, the cell containing G R P is split:

[image]

Based on the scarce information shared in your question, I assume that you have the line `table.setSplitLate(false);` somewhere in your code. If so, please remove it. If not, please share your code.

Comment: I updated the code you shared to reproduce the issue i am facing. Commented part is how i am actually adding text to the row-span cell.

Comment: Please let me know if you are able to reproduce the issue with code sample. I am not using "setSplitLate" flag. All i want is if the group name can't fit on the current page draw it on next page. The group name and no of rows for group are dynamically fetched from data source.

Comment: Hi, I reviewed my code and i was making a mistake. The example i shared was breaking as it couldn't fit the table on next page as well. The issue with my code was because of multiple level of tables.The outer table can't fit on one page completely so it was breaking as per the space on given page irrespective of whether the data in the internal table can fit on next page or not. Its working fine once i removed the outer table with slight changes to layout.